# Reuse a ReactJS template tag name in a different context

Tags: reactjs

I'm not exactly sure how to phrase this question so here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<NavMenu>
  <MenuItem />
  <MenuItem />
</NavMenu>
<ShortcutMenu>
  <MenuItem />
  <MenuItem />
</ShortcutMenu>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is if I can have two different components, both with the name MenuItem, one that is executed under the NavMenu context, and a separate one that is executed under the ShortcutMenu context. The two different MenuItems would be rendered into completely different HTML. I'm considering switching from AngularJS to ReactJS because when I've run into this issue in Angular I end up having to use names like NavMenu_MenuItem, which is just unpleasant.

I've been reading up on ReactJS and going through their Getting Started tutorial. I haven't found any obvious answer to this question. I'm assuming it's probably obvious once you understand some of the inner workings of ReactJS. But I don't have that understanding yet, and if this isn't possible then I might just stick with Angular.

Comment: How do you get them in scope?

Comment: Put every component (`NavMenu` and `ShortcutMenu`) into its own module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same thing than having two variables with the same name and different values, it all depends on the scope you are working in.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in your `NavMenu.js`.

```
class NavMenu extends React.Component{
...
}

NavMenu.MenuItem = require('./MenuItem');

export default NavMenu;
```

And the same for ShortcutMenu.

Now you can do

```
<NavMenu>
  <NavMenu.MenuItem />
  <NavMenu.MenuItem />
  <NavMenu.MenuItem />
</NavMenu>

<ShortcutMenu>
  <ShortcutMenu.MenuItem />
  <ShortcutMenu.MenuItem />
  <ShortcutMenu.MenuItem />
</ShortcutMenu>
```